# Unhide a Contact

Tags: contacts

I accidentally hid an individual contact. I cant' find a way to un-hide - I'm imagining an "Un-hide all contacts" option or something. Any ideas?

I'm using a Motorolla Droid XT907, Android version 4.1.2

Edit:

I did find this answer, but it's a bit invasive, as the original poster said: http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-razr-support/239955-unhide-read-only-contacts-2.html

Comment: And how did you hide that?

Comment: (contact name) > Menu > Delete. I was then prompted that I couldn't delete the contact via the "Contacts" app (because the contact came from another source), but that I could hide it. I accidentally hit "OK".

Comment: Other source, like the SIM card? I do not know how to naviagate these programs well yet, but I just find the settings , a view mode in contacts that shows the sim card contacts, or phone contacts, or all contacts?

Comment: I have the same issue on my Nexus 5. The trick didn't seem to solve anything.

Comment: @Jon did you recover the contact?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved a similar issue I had on my phone.

Since the contacts in question were synced through a gmail account, I went in my [contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/) and exported all of them to make a backup. Then I restored my contacts via the menu (More > Restore contacts...) to a day before the one on which I believed to have deleted the contact. The restore points go back to 30 days maximum.

From there I could import the backup I had downloaded earlier to merge with the freshly restored contacts.